# I have two user models using Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two user models one is 
1. User.rb (this is my own authentication system which handles users that just sign up within my site.

1. Authenticate.rb (this is the OmniAuth authentication for users that want to signup through facebook.

Im having a hard time handling both models.....for example here is the code for my navigation

```
   - if fb_signed_in?
      .nav.pull-right.padding-top
        %li
        - if fb_signed_in?
          %li#fat-menu.dropdown
            %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", :href => "#"}
              %span
                Signed in as
                = fb_current_user.email              
            %ul.dropdown-menu
              %li= link_to "Profile", "#"
              %li.divider
              %li= link_to "Sign out", leave_path, method: "get"             
        - else 
          .nav.pull-right
          %span.light_color Already a Member?
          = link_to "Sign in", signin_path, class: 'light_color'
          %span.light_color or
          = link_to "Sign up", signup_path, class: 'light_color' 

    - else
      .nav.pull-right.padding-top
        %li
        - if signed_in?
          %li#fat-menu.dropdown
            %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", :href => "#"}
              %span
                Signed in as
                = current_user.email              
            %ul.dropdown-menu
              %li= link_to "Profile", "#"
              %li.divider
              %li= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "get"             
        - else 
          .nav.pull-right
          %span.light_color Already a Member?
          = link_to "Sign in", signin_path, class: 'light_color'
          %span.light_color or
          = link_to "Sign up", signup_path, class: 'light_color'
```

So i have defined a fb_signed_in? adn a signed_in? which basically does the same thing though..also with current_user and fb_current_user but heres the code for both

current_user

```
    def current_user
  @current_user = @current_user ||    
       User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
    end
```

and this is for fb_current_user

```
    def fb_current_user
      @fb_current_user ||= Authenticate.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end
```

so they do do different things....but is there a way to make those two one...since it will be a lot cleaner and im trying to create a comment system that will print users name and gravatar image and im getting confused on how to write the code for that since it uses gravatar_for @user and i would also have to do gravatar_for @authenticate for fb users.

Im basically using Hartl's authentication and trying to integrate Omniauth with it

Please let me know if the question is confusing or unclear and i will try to explain better

Thank You

Comment: Why do you have a `if fb_signed_in?` nested inside another `if fb_signed_in?` block? No case will ever reach the `else` condition there.

Comment: Also could you post your `signed_in?` and `fb_signed_in?` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
def current_user
  if session[:user_id]
    @current_user ||= Authenticate.find(session[:user_id])
  else
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end
end

def signed_in?
  current_user.is_a?(User) || current_user.is_a?(Authenticate)
end
```

Although this may cause problems in other places since you don't know what a `current_user` is without testing its type.

In my projects I have just one `User` model which has many `Authorizations`, where I put the omniauth-related stuff (so `current_user` is always a `User`).

Comment: so to do that i would have to state in my USER.rb has_many Authorizations......and in my authorization model add belongs_to users......and what column would i have to add to the user model to relate it?  the provider and uid?  Thank you for your previous answer i didnt know you could do that im still very new to programming.....